# Nodejs nodemailer Username and Password not accepted

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to send mails with nodejs and nodemailer, but it doesn't work for me. I have this code:

```
const config = require('../../config');
const http = require('http');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

module.exports = {

    sendMail: function (params) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                //service: 'gmail', //I tried with this too
                host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
                port: 465,
                secure: true,
                auth: {
                    user: params.fromMail,
                    pass: params.fromPass
                }
            });

            var mailOptions = {
                from: params.fromMail,
                to: params.toMailList,
                subject: params.subject,
                html: params.mailHtmlContent,
            };

            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info){
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(info.response);
                }
            });


        });
    }

};
```

I'm getting this error:

> { Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
>   Learn more at 535 5.7.8 
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials p6sm97493129wrx.50 -
>   gsmtp
>       at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop\Proyectos\nodeServer\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:774:19)
>       at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop\Proyectos\nodeServer\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1509:34)
>       at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop\Proyectos\nodeServer\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:547:26)
>       at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop\Proyectos\nodeServer\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:933:20)
>       at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop\Proyectos\nodeServer\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:739:14)
>       at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop\Proyectos\nodeServer\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:691:47)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
>       at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)   code: 'EAUTH',   response:    '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
>   Learn more at\n535 5.7.8 
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials p6sm97493129wrx.50 -
>   gsmtp',   responseCode: 535,   command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }

I have changed the correspondant param on my gmail account about "less secure apps".
I tried with another non gmail account too.
I tried with this:

```
service: 'gmail',
```

and this for the connection:

```
host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
port: 465,
secure: true,
```

I read all "Similar Questions" here in stackoverflow and I don't know if I need anything else or if I'm doing anything bad. (of course I have revieved the username and password in both accounts and they're ok).

What am Im doing bad?

Comment: Did you try with `secure: false`? If it still doesn't work, try with `secure: true` but `port: 587`.

Comment: Hi, I have an error "Error: Unexpected socket close" with "secure: false" and an error "{ [Error: 16212:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:252:
] code: 'ECONNECTION', command: 'CONN' }" with port = 587 and secure = true

Comment: Other resources on the Web are mentioning to do the step on this link: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha
I am afraid I can't be that much more helpful after that.

Comment: yes I forgot to mention that I tried with that unlock too, but thank you anyway

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',//smtp.gmail.com  //in place of service use host...
  secure: false,//true
  port: 25,//465
  auth: {
    user: 'example@gmail.com',
    pass: 'password'
  }, tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});

transporter.sendEMail = function (mailRequest) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    transporter.sendMail(mailRequest, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve("The message was sent!");
      }
    });
  });
}

module.exports = transporter;
```

**Usage**:

```
//import transporter JS file
const mail = require('../utils/mail');
let htmlContent = `
                <h1><strong>Contact Form</strong></h1>
                <p>Hi,</p>
                <p>${name} contacted with the following Details</p>
                <br/>
                <p>Email: ${email}</p>
                <p>Phone: ${phone}</p>
                <p>Company Name: ${companyName}</p>
                <p>Message: ${message}</p>
                `
    let mailOptions = {
        from: "Example <example@gmail.com>",
        to: "me@gmail.com",
        subject: "Mail Test",
        text: "",
        html: htmlContent
    }

mail.sendMail(mailOptions)
    .then(function (email) {
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, msg: 'Mail sent' });
    }).catch(function (exception) {
        res.status(200).json({ success: false, msg: exception });
    });
```

***Note:***

1. Before sending your email using gmail you have to allow non secure apps to access gmail you can do this by going to your gmail settings
   https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1
2. Also enable the captcha
   https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: ok I don't know why, but with port "port: 25" it works (with the original code too). Lots of thanks (clear answer and well defined).

Comment: I'm also getting issues with this. Changing to port 25 did not fix it for me.

Comment: Could you share your code.. So i can have a look at it @Soubriquet

Comment: I think that the problem is not due to the nodemailer transporter configuration but to the gmail restriction. You sould  allow non secure apps to access gmail before sending emails. I think that is the problem. With the same configuration described in the question I'm able to send emails.

Comment: hello, i did all this config, and i allowed no secured applications, but it's not working !

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me. These four steps did:

- Sign in to your Google Admin console using an administrator account.
- From the Admin console dashboard, go to Security and then Basic settings (you might have to click More controls at the bottom).
- Under Less secure apps, select Go to settings for less secure apps.
- In the subwindow, select the Enable access to less secure apps for all users radio button.